# Draw lines between buttons in web page that has tree structure

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have code in asp.net and want the buttons to be connected by line and arrow in tree form and specific button and line should hide if it is not selected by user, so it should have coding in C#. My problem is i am not able to draw lines between these specific buttons on web page.[image]

Comment: Since you have the code, can you share it with us? That'll allow us to have a solution that is tailored to your question.

Comment: you can use <canvas> as background...But I will suggest you to use [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com) library to draw everything it also allows you to specify handler for each object.

Comment: Code i have is only of <asp:button/> and they are <div> for one line example <div><asp:button text="1"/></div> then <div><asp:button text="2"/><asp:button text="3"/><asp:button text="4"/></div> and so on..